# What do "--", "-d", etc in file_contexts mean?

Tags: linux, selinux

In `/etc/selinux/targeted/contexts/files/file_contexts`, some lines will have just two parts, with the context as the second part, but some will have three parts where the second part is `--`, `-d`, etc.  What do these mean?  I've looked through the documentation I can find but as far as I can tell none of them mention it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The -d means to match only directories, the -- means to match only
>   files.

Original link to documentation - [Understanding the File Contexts Files.](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/SELinux_Guide/rhlcommon-section-0037.html)

Comment: Ah, so `-l` means only symbolic links, `-b` means only block devices and `-c` means only character devices.  Got it.